# Change background color of gridview row while processing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What I need to do is to highlight each row when it is processing to show the process progress, the gridview may contain almost one thousands of row. below is the code I have written but which doesn't work.
Please can someone help me.

<

```
asp:GridView ID="gdview1" runat="server" BackColor="White"
                BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
                ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Font-Names="Calibri"
                Font-Size="Small" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnRowDataBound="gdview1_RowDataBound"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="gdview1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxHeader" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNUM" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNUM" runat="server" DataField="ColNUM" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row#">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ColNUM" HeaderText="Contract #" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Col1" HeaderText="Suffix" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Col2" HeaderText="First Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Col3" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Col4" HeaderText="Street" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Col5" HeaderText="City" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Col6" HeaderText="Zip" />

                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />

            </asp:GridView>




 namespace WebApplication1
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            protected void butChargeCreditCards_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                DataTable tblContrts = (DataTable) Session["tblContrts"];

                foreach (GridViewRow row in gdview1.Rows)
                {

                    CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox) row.FindControl("chkNUM");

                    if (chkbx != null && chkbx.Checked)
                    {

                        gdview1_SelectedIndexChanged(row,e);



                        string SS = chkbx.Text.ToString();



                        string strResults = method1;



                    }


                }

            }


            protected void gdview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow row in gdview1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex == gdview1.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that, since it's ASP.NET, you'd have to send a response back to the client each time you want to highlight the next row (this would be insanely inefficient).  Consider looking into sending back asynchronous responses to the client using Ajax or such.  Have a look at the ASP.NET page lifecycle to understand how ASP.NET processes requests http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just to be clear, the code you provided is logically sound, but ASP.NET won't update any controls on the client until it's completely finished on the server side and ready to return, which would be after butChargeCreditCards_Click() has completed execution.  You might find that the last row is being selected on the client after completion, since the selected index was set to it just before the method finishes (last run of the foreach loop)

Comment: Why dont you use a progress bar? like this [Using Modal Popup Extender][1]


or like this:[Iframe][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059067/asp-net-display-progress-bar-during-post-back
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156899/asp-reporting-long-running-server-process-is-this-the-best-way

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick reply. I have implemented a wait gif icon and proposed a progress bar but the client(user) still want to follow the progress row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it by using the "OnRowDataBound" or "OnRowCreated" Event of the Grid and write the color-highliting in code behind?

Something like this?
http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/ADO.net-Database/UsingtheRowCreatedEventtoprogrammaticallychangethestyle.htm

But maybe you have a problem because the loading would be too fast to really notice?